# Is There a Way to Dynamically Reference Variables Declared with let and const

Tags: javascript, variables

I could do this with variables declared with `var`:

```
var a = 1;
console.log(window['a'])
```

But is there a way to achieve the same goal with variables declared with `let` or `const`?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: No unless eval is involved. And yes, it looks like XY problem.

Comment: The point of let and const is to stop this

Comment: *"But is there a way to achieve the same goal with variables declared with `let` or `const`?"* Not without dynamically-compiled code (`eval` or `new Function`), which should be a last resort (at most). By design, `let` and `const` variables do not become part of any object you can reference in your code. If you need to access things by name like that, explicitly use an object: `const stuff = {a: 1}; console.log(stuff["a"]);`